# Duration of a Gambler's Ruin game against an opponent with infinite credit

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, recurrence-relations, random-variables, random-walk

A gambler enters the casino with $x\$$ in his pocket and sits on some table.

At each iteration he bets $1\$$ and either wins $1\$$ with probability $p\leq\frac{1}{2}$ or loses $1\$$.

Assuming that the casino has unlimited credit, it's simple to see that the gambler will eventually get bankrupt.

> **How is the time till bankruptcy distributed?**
>
> **Is the expected time till bankruptcy == $\infty$?**

Comment: Going left or right has same probability?

Comment: @drhab - yes, thanks.

Comment: @drhab - although if we can get the distribution when going lower is w.p. $p\geq \frac{1}{2}$ it's also interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is the time till bankruptcy distributed?

This is an application of the Hitting Time Theorem (see, e.g. [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rhofstad/monthly753-756-hofstad.pdf) (Theorem 1) or pg. 79 of Grimmett and Stirzaker).

$$P(\text{Ruined at game $n$ starting with $\$x$}) = \dfrac{x}{n}\binom{n}{(n-x)/2}p^{(n-x)/2}q^{(n+x)/2}.$$

> Is the expected time till bankruptcy $= \infty$?

Yes, if $p\geq q$. Otherwise, it is

$$\dfrac{x}{q-p}.$$

Ref: e.g. [Section 2.1.2 of here](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/huiwang/classes/APMA1200/RWalk_07.pdf) or G&S pg. 74. In both references take the limit as casino's fortune approaches $\infty$ because they assume a finite casino amount.